# Keras multi_gpu_model returns error 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I have problems training my unet model on both my gpu's,

The model is a simple U-net implementation that i know works, since its testet without being a multi_gpu_model

```
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    # initialize the model
    model = unet((512,512,3))

# make the model parallel
model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mean_squared_error")

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=250, epochs=10)

:output
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/U-net/U-net.py", line 29, in <module>
    model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 150, in multi_gpu_model
    available_devices = _get_available_devices()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 16, in _get_available_devices
    return K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus() + ['/cpu:0']
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 506, in _get_available_gpus
    _LOCAL_DEVICES = tf.config.experimental_list_devices()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'
```

I have also tried tf.distributed.mirroredStrategy() but also without luck

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

experimental_list_devices is deprecated in tf 2.1,use tf.config.list_logical_devices replaced.

```
def _get_available_gpus():
"""Get a list of available gpu devices (formatted as strings).

# Returns
    A list of available GPU devices.
"""
global _LOCAL_DEVICES
if _LOCAL_DEVICES is None:
    if _is_tf_1():
        devices = get_session().list_devices()
        _LOCAL_DEVICES = [x.name for x in devices]
    else:
        devices = tf.config.list_logical_devices()
        _LOCAL_DEVICES = [x.name for x in devices]
return [x for x in _LOCAL_DEVICES if 'device:gpu' in x.lower()]
```

The link is helpful in solving your issue [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581677/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-core-api-v2-config-has-no-attribute-expe)

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the error, but still only uses 1 gpu to train.

Comment: It dose add the replicas to each gpu, but when allocation memory/training it only uses GPU:0