# Trying to fix the construction of a neural network (error message: negative dimension?)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

This is a model based on the description on page 12, section B.3 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04836.pdf

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
img_size = (3, 32, 32)

...

def shallownet(nb_classes):
    global img_size
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=img_size, data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(384))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(192))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

Which I attempted to convert as a result of Keras 2.0. Here is the original code: https://github.com/keskarnitish/large-batch-training/blob/master/network_zoo.py

I try to run the following code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=
                '''This code first trains the user-specific network (C[1-4])
                using small-batch ADAM and large-batch ADAM, and then plots
                the parametric plot connecting the two minimizers
                illustrating the sharpness difference.''')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--network', help='''Selects which network
                    to plot the parametric plots for.
                    Choices are C1, C2, C3 and C4.''', required=True)
network_choice = vars(parser.parse_args())['network']


nb_epoch = 20

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
if network_choice in ['C1', 'C2']:
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
    nb_classes = 10
elif network_choice in ['C3', 'C4']:
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
    nb_classes = 100
else:
    raise ValueError('''Invalid choice of network.
                     Please choose one of C1, C2, C3 or C4.
                     Refer to the paper for details regarding these networks''')

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

# build the network
if network_choice in ['C1', 'C3']:
    model = network_zoo.shallownet(nb_classes)
elif network_choice in ['C2', 'C4']:
    model = network_zoo.deepnet(nb_classes)
# let's train the model using Adam
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.save_weights('x0.h5')

# let's first find the small-batch solution
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=256,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
          shuffle=True)
```

And receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_parametric_plot.py", line 64, in <module>
    model = network_zoo.shallownet(nb_classes)
  File "/mnt_home/klee/LBSBGenGapSharpnessResearch/network_zoo.py", line 36, in shallownet
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=img_size))
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 166, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 171, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3717, in conv2d
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 918, in convolution_v2
    name=name)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1010, in convolution_internal
    name=name)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 969, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 742, in _apply_op_helper
    attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 595, in _create_op_internal
    compute_device)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3322, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1786, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1622, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 3 for 'conv2d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,3,32,32], [5,5,32,64].
```

Though I'm not sure what this means...

UPDATE: after writing in Marco Celani's comment, here's the new error message I receive after running the main code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_parametric_plot.py", line 64, in <module>
    model = network_zoo.shallownet(nb_classes)
  File "/mnt_home/klee/LBSBGenGapSharpnessResearch/network_zoo.py", line 36, in shallownet
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=img_size, data_format='channels_first'))
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 166, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 171, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3701, in conv2d
    x, tf_data_format = _preprocess_conv2d_input(x, data_format)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3574, in _preprocess_conv2d_input
    if not _has_nchw_support() or force_transpose:
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 522, in _has_nchw_support
    gpus_available = len(_get_available_gpus()) > 0
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 506, in _get_available_gpus
    _LOCAL_DEVICES = tf.config.experimental_list_devices()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'
```

Comment: Is this the same error after edit?

Comment: Sorry yes I pasted the wrong code in. The new code I put in the original post (the edit to the post) is what originally caused the error.

Comment: After I inputed your fix to the convolutional layers, I get the following error: Traceback 
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 522, in _has_nchw_support
    gpus_available = len(_get_available_gpus()) > 0
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 506, in _get_available_gpus
    _LOCAL_DEVICES = tf.config.experimental_list_devices()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'

Comment: do you use gpu?

Comment: I ran the code right underneath "I try to run the following code" in original post, which hasn't loaded the model onto a GPU

Comment: I also added data_format='channels_first' to the pooling layers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581677/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-core-api-v2-config-has-no-attribute-expe

Comment: I also suggest you to try with tf.keras

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214516/discussion-between-klee-and-marco-cerliani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means that you can't apply any operation because you reduce too much the dimension inside your network (it is below 0).

Looking at your data format seems like your images are (3, 32, 32), so the channels are the first dimension. Keras by default applies convolution with channels in the last dimensions. To override the error try to define `data_format='channels_first'` in convolutional and in pooling layers