# Is there an issue using tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model with a Model Class API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a convolutional autoencoder using tensorflow.keras. Here, I have a Model Class API (I think that is what it's called) that works using a single GPU (not implementing multi_gpu_model). However, when I transition to this on a machine with 4 GPUs, I am getting an error when defining the multiple GPU model (here called parallel_autoencoder). I have done this in the past using the Keras Model API and this syntax had worked just fine.

I believe the problem is stemming from the use of the Model Class API, but I am not entirely sure of that. Below is the relevant code and the error message I am getting. I would just try to use the Model API with tensorflow.keras, but I am not able to get the Flatten layer to work with that, because I get the error "TypeError: object of type 'Flatten' has no len()".

I am really looking for advice on the multi_gpu_model issue, but if anyone knows a workaround for the Flatten issue, I would appreciate that as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling3D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Reshape, UpSampling3D

latent_dim = 100
class Autoencoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4096,4096,3,1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(4, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'), #72 x 32 x 2 x 16
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(8, 8, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(8, 8, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim,activation='sigmoid')
        ])
        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(latent_dim,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16*64*64, activation='sigmoid'),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape((64,64,1,16)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D((8, 8, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(4, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D((8, 8, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(1, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
        ])
        self.decoder.summary()
    def call(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded

model = Autoencoder(latent_dim)

parallel_autoencoder = tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
parallel_autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adadelta')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SDO_TFR_Multi_GPU.py", line 102, in 
parallel_autoencoder = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 150, in multi_gpu_model
available_devices = _get_available_devices()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 16, in _get_available_devices
return K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus() + ['/cpu:0']
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 506, in _get_available_gpus
_LOCAL_DEVICES = tf.config.experimental_list_devices()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the problem is not the usage of `Model()` API.

The problem is that there are some issues with the `tensorflow.keras` and plain `keras` compatiblity and my intuition tells me (according to the error you posted) that there is a problem with the `multi_gpu` function, in that it doesn't correctly detect the available devices.

Not surprised, since the official TensorFlow documentation states it clearly that:

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after
> 2020-04-01. Instructions for updating: Use
> tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy instead.

Someone here had a similar problem: [{ AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices' } how can i solve this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581677/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-core-api-v2-config-has-no-attribute-expe)

My strong recommendation is to switch to `MirroredStrategy()` if you want to train the model on `multi_gpus`. Not only do you avoid such problems but it's also the recommended way in the foreseeable future.