# Keras: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, keras

I'm working on a model based on an older version of Keras, and when I want to use multi-gpu, they import it as follows:

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
 multi_model = multi_gpu_model(myModel, gpus=args.gpus)
```

I have change the import to:

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils as multi_gpu_model
```

which results in an error for me:

```
multi_model: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

utils is not a function, try maybe:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
```

or:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model as m_g_m
```

Comment: Both raises the same error "cannot import name 'multi_gpu_model' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils'"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Python's import syntax is a little ambiguous about what you're importing.

Here you are importing a *function* called `multi_gpu_model` that is inside the module `utils`, you can tell because you can call `multi_gpu_model`:

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
```

This first way is used when you only need a few specific functions. You still import the whole module, but it's not bound to a name for you to use.

Here you are importing the module `utils` and renaming it to `multi_gpu_model`:

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils as multi_gpu_model
```

Don't do the second way, you clearly expect a function `multi_gpu_model` but you used up the name renaming a module.

I suspect your intention is to bind the module to a name so you can use all its functions. Just do this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils

multi_model = utils.multi_gpu_model(myModel, gpus=args.gpus)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, unfortunately it raises another error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.utils' has no attribute 'multi_gpu_model'

Comment: Weird, does it work if you change the import to `from keras import utils`?

Comment: No "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.utils' has no attribute 'multi_gpu_model'
"

Comment: Does `from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model` still work for you? I checked online and apparently `multi_gpu_model` is deprecated, that could have something to do with all these problems.

Comment: Yes, I checked it now, and it's deprecated. I'll use "MirroredStrategy" instead, thanks for your help. "https://stackoverflow.com/a/65104465/15164196"